# How to calculate arithmetic expression of column members database table?

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I have result from this query

```
SELECT
    myTable.Branch AS Branch,
    myTable.Quarter AS Quarter,
    SUM(myTable.Sales) AS Sales
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    myTable.Branch,
    myTable.Quarter

Branch  Quarter Sales
B1      Q1      17
B1      Q2      7
B1      Q3      1
B1      Q4      8
B1      Q5      12
B2      Q1      8
B2      Q2      5
B2      Q3      2
B2      Q4      14
B2      Q5      17
```

Now I want to get calculate member lets say `Q1-Q3` then result should look like

```
Branch  Quarter     Sales
B1      Q1          17
B1      Q2          7
B1      Q3          1
B1      Q4          8
B1      Q5          12
B1      Q1-Q3       16
B2      Q1          8
B2      Q2          5
B2      Q3          2
B2      Q4          14
B2      Q5          17
B2      Q1-Q3       6
```

Expression can be any valid arithmetic expression like `(Q1+Q2-Q3)*2`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table that has Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 as columns for each branch:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eca51/14/0

```
SELECT
    Branch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q1' THEN sales END) AS Q1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q2' THEN sales END) AS Q2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q3' THEN sales END) AS Q3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q4' THEN sales END) AS Q4
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY Branch
```

This gives:

```
| BRANCH | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
|--------|----|----|----|----|
|     B1 | 17 |  7 |  1 |  8 |
|     B2 |  8 |  5 |  2 | 13 |
```

You can use that as a sub-query and perform any arithmetic you like.

```
SELECT Branch, Q1+2*Q2 AS Weighted,SQRT(Q1*Q2) GeometricMean
  FROM (
  SELECT
      Branch,
      SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q1' THEN sales END) AS Q1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q2' THEN sales END) AS Q2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q3' THEN sales END) AS Q3,
      SUM(CASE WHEN quarter='Q4' THEN sales END) AS Q4
  FROM
      sales
 GROUP BY Branch) AS BQ
```

This gives:

```
| BRANCH | WEIGHTED |   GEOMETRICMEAN |
|--------|----------|-----------------|
|     B1 |       31 | 10.908712114636 |
|     B2 |       18 |  6.324555320337 |
```

This relies on the number of quarters being known and fixed - I'd have guessed there were 4 but you seem to have 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.Branch, m.Quarter, m.Sales
FROM (SELECT m.Branch, m.Quarter, SUM(m.Sales) AS Sales
      FROM myTable m
      GROUP BY m.Branch, m.Quarter
      UNION 
      SELECT m.Branch, 'Q1+Q3' AS `Quarter`, SUM(m.Sales) AS Sales
      FROM myTable m 
      WHERE m.Quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q3')
      GROUP BY m.Branch
     ) AS m 
ORDER BY m.Branch, m.Quarter;
```

Comment: This will just work if there is only sum in between operand. What if expression is Q1*2 or Q1-Q2 or Q1/Q2?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
First get output of your first query through CTE

;With cte(Branch, Quarter, Sales)
As
(SELECT
    myTable.Branch AS Branch,
    myTable.Quarter AS Quarter,
    SUM(myTable.Sales) AS Sales
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    myTable.Branch,
    myTable.Quarter)

Select Branch, Quarter, Sales
From CTE

Union

Select Branch, 'Q1-Q3' AS Quarter, 'Q1 Sales -Q3 Sales' AS Sales
From CTE